# Unable to update table in Advanced Data Persistence mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, dom-events, gupshup

I have an issue related to database. I am currently working with Gupshup bot programming. There are two different data persistence modes which can be read [here](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/adding-advanced-persistence) and [here](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/adding-basic-data-persistence). In the advanced data persistence, the following code is documented to put data into data base:

```
function MessageHandler(context, event) {
      if(event.message=='update bug - 1452') {
         jiraUpdate(context);
    }
          }
   function jiraUpdate(context){
       //connect to Jira and check for latest update and values
       if(true){
      context.simpledb.doPut("1452" ,"{\"status\":\"QA pending\",\"lastUpdated\":\"06\/05\/2016\",\"userName\":\"John\",\"comment\":\"Dependent on builds team to provide right build\"}");
} else{
         context.sendResponse('No new updates');
}
  }
function DbPutHandler(context, event) {
      context.sendResponse("New update in the bug, type in the bug id to see the update");
     }
```

If I want to change only one of column (say status or last Updated) in the table for the row with key value 1452, I am unable to do that. How can that be done?

I used the following code:

```
function MessageHandler(context, event) {
    // var nlpToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";//Your API.ai token
    // context.sendResponse(JSON.stringify(event));
if(event.message=='deposit') {
         context.sendResponse("Enter the amount to be deposited");
    }
    
     if(event.message=="1000") {
        jiraUpdate(context);
    }
    
    if(event.message== "show"){
context.simpledb.doGet("1452");
         
    }
}

function HttpResponseHandler(context, event) {
           var dateJson = JSON.parse(event.getresp);
           var date = dateJson.date;
           context.sendResponse("Today's date is : "+date+":-)");
       }
            
function jiraUpdate(context){
       //connect to Jira and check for latest update and values
       if(true){
      context.simpledb.doPut("aaa" ,"{\"account_number\":\"90400\",\"balance\":\"5800\"}");
} else{
         context.sendResponse('No new updates');
}

 }

/** Functions declared below are required **/
function EventHandler(context, event) {
    if (!context.simpledb.botleveldata.numinstance)
        context.simpledb.botleveldata.numinstance = 0;
    numinstances = parseInt(context.simpledb.botleveldata.numinstance) + 1;
    context.simpledb.botleveldata.numinstance = numinstances;
    context.sendResponse("Thanks for adding me. You are:" + numinstances);
}



function DbGetHandler(context, event) {
    var bugObj = JSON.parse(event.dbval);
             var bal = bugObj.balance;
  var acc = bugObj.account_number;
  context.sendResponse(bal);
  var a = parseInt (bal,10);
  var b = a +1000;
  var num = b.toString();
  context.simpledb.doPut.aaa.balance = num;
  
  
}

function DbPutHandler(context, event) {
    context.sendResponse("testdbput keyword was last put by:" + event.dbval);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the hosted DB that is provided by Gupshup is the **DynamoDB** of AWS. Hence you can enter something as a key, value pair.

Hence you will have to set the right key while using **doPut** method to store data into the database and use the same key to get the data from the database using the **doGet** method.

To update the data you should first call **doGet** method and then update the JSON with right data and then call **doPut** method to update the database with the latest data.

I have also added something which is not present in the documentation, You can now make DB calls and choose which function the response goes to.

I am refactoring your example as using 3 keywords and hard coding few things just for example -

1. **have** - this will update the database with these values

   `{"account_number":"90400","balance":"5800"}`
2. **deposit** - on this, the code will add 1000 to the balance
3. **show**  - on this, the code show the balance to the user.

Code -

```
function MessageHandler(context, event) {

if(event.message=='have') {
    var data = {"account_number":"90400","balance":"5800"};
      context.simpledb.doPut(event.sender,JSON.stringify(data),insertData); //using event.sender to keep the key unique
      return;
    }
if(event.message=="deposit") {
   context.simpledb.doGet(event.sender, updateData);
    return;
}
if(event.message== "show"){
context.simpledb.doGet(event.sender);
return;
    }
}
function insertData(context){
    context.sendResponse("I have your data now. To update just say \"deposit\"");
}
function updateData(context,event){
  var bugObj = JSON.parse(event.dbval);
 
  var bal = bugObj.balance;
  var a = parseInt(bal,10);
  var b = a + 1000;
  var num = b.toString();
  bugObj.balance = num;
 
 context.simpledb.doPut(event.sender,bugObj);
}

function EventHandler(context, event) {
    if (!context.simpledb.botleveldata.numinstance)
        context.simpledb.botleveldata.numinstance = 0;
    numinstances = parseInt(context.simpledb.botleveldata.numinstance) + 1;
    context.simpledb.botleveldata.numinstance = numinstances;
    context.sendResponse("Thanks for adding me. You are:" + numinstances);
}

function DbGetHandler(context, event) {
     var accountObj = JSON.parse(event.dbval);
     context.sendResponse(accountObj);
}

function DbPutHandler(context, event) {
    context.sendResponse("I have updated your data. Just say \"show\" to view the data.");
}
```